# Copying files in Javascript Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

I'm looking for the easiest solution to copy a file from `/pathA/filename` to `/pathB/filename`. No relative paths or file modifications are needed.

I'm trying to copy a file in Javascript Rhino. The code below for making a new file works with no issues:

```
        //Make destination file
        destinationDir = new java.io.File(filepath).mkdirs();
        localFile = new java.io.File(filepath,filename);
        localFile.createNewFile();
```

I just need to copy the file with no modifications, so there is no need for copying an input/output stream. Any suggestions? Many of the other related questions I've found are for java or javascript with html, neither of which give me an exact solution. I've tried `Files.copy` but can't seem to get it correct.

Comment: Looks like Java, not JavaScript

Comment: @Vivick when programming in Rhino (JavaScript hooked up to Java) it's common to access Java classes like that.

Comment: @Vivick 95% of my code is just API calls, the snippet above is the only java class I'm using (so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do just as you would in Java:

```
sourceFile = new java.io.File(/* [...] */);

//Make destination file
destinationDir = new java.io.File(filepath).mkdirs();
localFile = new java.io.File(filepath,filename);
localFile.createNewFile();

java.nio.file.Files.copy(
    sourceFile.toPath(),
    localFile.toPath(),
    java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work with a couple of small changes. Rhino requires you to import all used classes, so I imported the two java.nio.files functions and modified the code accordingly: `importClass(java.nio.file.Files);
importClass(java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption);

Files.copy(
 sourceFile.toPath(),
 destFile.toPath(),
 StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
);`